# Get the value from a single line XML response

Tags: javascript, xml, asp-classic, response

I have the result of a web service call returned to my application. I need to get the  result of the generated pdf name. Can anyone suggest a method of doing this in Classic Asp or Javascript.

I've tried  various methods of trying to get the value using xPath etc.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.Namespace goes here">635672928228907180.pdf</string>
```

Comment: Can you post something about your tries and what precisely didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was unable to get the value using of any of the methods to extract data from the node. In the end i had to use a regular expression to achieve it.

```
pdfNewUniqueID.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use classic ASP, this should work

```
dim input
input = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
        "<string xmlns=""http://www.Namespace goes" & _
        " here"">635672928228907180.pdf</string>"

dim objxml
Set objxml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

objxml.LoadXml( input)
dim node
set node = objxml.selectSingleNode("string")

Response.Write( node.text)
```